# Cannot GET /path using ReactJS, webpack, express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've tried almost every solution but I can't find any solution for this problem. I'm using express to render my ReactJS code, build with webpack. I can open pages without any issues until I'm being redirected from home page. But when I tried entering the URL on browser or refresh the page, I cannot see the page. Instead I see this error:

`Cannot GET /path`

I have also tried adding `historyApiFallback: true` to my **webpack.config.js** but no luck there.

Below are my scripts from `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "start": "npm run build && node server.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

And this is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require('path');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [htmlPlugin],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
};
```

And the `server.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(PORT, error => (
  error
    ? console.error(error)
    : console.info(`Listening on port ${PORT}. Visit http://localhost:${PORT}/ in your browser.`)
));
```

**Important NOTE**

When I run server with `npm run dev`, there is no issues. I can enter URL manually and refresh the page.

But when I run server with `npm run start`, I am facing the issue I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.get('/', ... );` only sends back the `index.html` on the `/` path, you need to return it on *every* path

```js
app.get('*', function(request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});
```